# FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create')

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response){
window.location="app-page.php";
});
```

With these code,  User like now , window location is "app-page.php" . This is good , no problem.

But user like my page before , window location is not send to "app-page.php" .

I want to control likes, if people like my page now or before, they can see aplication . Else Require they like my page.

For Example

http://www.facebook.com/Ulker/app_440168149393686
http://www.facebook.com/Zirve/app_190322544333196

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are replicating those apps in facebook then you could do the following in PHP via the Facebook SDK which you should be using for the apps! This will work for the in-site like button.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => FBAPP_KEY,
'secret' => FBAPP_SECRET,
'cookie' => true,   
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$liked = $signed_request['page']['liked'];

if ($liked == 1):
    //have liked show data
else:
    //haven't liked show a like button
endif;
```

The Facebook platform will do the rest unless you have a reason not to do it this way?

The below functionality will only work with the like button plugin [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). Not the built in Facebook like button:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
    window.location = 'url_here';
});
```

and

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response){
    window.location="url_here";
});
```